# How to insert a section break in a Pages '09 Page Layout document?

Tags: pages, iwork, formatting

I have a Page Layout document. I need to remove the header and page numbering from the title page. So, I want to insert a section break after the title page. The problem is, I cannot do that. No matter where I click in the document - page one, page two, a textbox/shape/outside of them on page one or two, when I click the Insert menu -> "Section Break" is greyed out.

I searched everywhere, but I constantly stumble to threads where people discuss how to remove headers/pages numbers from the first page rather than how to actually insert the section break. I think the problem might be that I use Page Layout and not Word Processor, but I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your actual question? How to remove page numbers from the first page, or inset a section break in a layout document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can't!

You can't insert a section break in a layout document because layout documents don't have sections; each page it its own section. See [Creating Sections:](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10249)

> In a page layout document, each page is one section. You can use the predefined sections as they are, or you can modify or remove them one page at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My problem was that I wanted to remove the headers and footers/page numbers from the title page. Everywhere I search the solution was to insert a section break. In a Page Layout document, as David Pearce points out, there are no section breaks. So what worked out for me is the following:

1) If you have any headers/footer, you save them somewhere outside your Pages document.

2) You remove the headers and footers

3) You switch them back on -> they are empty now.

4) You go to the page, from where you want the headers and footers to start (in my case the first page after my title page).

5) You go to the Inspector windows and on the second tab, under Section, you uncheck "Use previous headers and footers".

6) You define your headers and footers on that same page and this way the headers and footers of the title page stay empty, but all other pagers have proper headers/footers and numbering.